# Can't Convert to String some special Chars

Tags: account, excel, blob, fileupload

I have a file to insert Accounts ,but some fields like account name have values with special characters like 'ñ' ,and Im having this error "BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string" when I execute this query:

```
StaticResource srObject = [select id,body 
from StaticResource Where Name = 'NewAccountInsert'];
String contents = srObject.body.toString();
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your file, at the time of upload, was encoded in some other encoding - perhaps ISO Latin-1 or Codepage 1252. All strings in Salesforce are required to be encoded in valid UTF-8.

Converting encodings in Apex is not supported natively. Instead, convert the file at the point of origin to UTF-8 encoding and upload that version. This is possible in many spreadsheet applications, or you can use a programmer's editor like Visual Studio Code to convert the file to UTF-8.

Comment: It worked perfectly with Visual Studio Code,thanks!